# Why does shift+rightclick run as admin/another user work for .bat, but not for .ps1 scripts?

Tags: windows-10, command-line, powershell, credentials

Im on Windows 10 Enterprise. I want to run an AD Script that moves around objects, but that of course needs admin credentials every time its run. I know you can get credentials to run in powershell itself, but compared to a simple shift+right click that doesnt seem very good to me - sadly the "run as another user" Windows feature doesnt seem to work for .ps1 files. Anyone knows why, and if i cant make it work?

Comment: There are some solutions here to your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989750/running-powershell-as-another-user-and-launching-a-script/34307483

Comment: I saw this before and tested it, but it didnt work for me - always says credentials are wrong, tried entering domain/name and other stuff but nothing worked. I also tried using a bat to run the ps1 and running the bat as another user, but this would require 2 files for something simple which is also meh

Comment: if you scroll down a bit, you will find a solution without any bat files. Have you tested the credentials you're using to run the script?

Comment: None of the other solutions are really satisfying - the from DukeOfMuppets would require me to prompt for credentials using normal powershell prompts, which would show the passwords in plain-text; my other option was storing the .ps1 on a server and only putting one .bat on the desktop, but thats not working due to UNC paths, and pushd did not work here either